# What is it wrong with this power function?

Tags: c, function

I am making my own power function(see below). It works but the input enters the loop just once so if in main I have: `x=power(10, 3);`  the output is `100` instead of `1000`.
Do you have any idea?
Thank you in advance.

```
 int power(int a, int b) {
    int p=a;
    for (int i=1; i<=b; i++) {
        if ((b!=1) && (b!=0)) {
            a= p*a;
        }
        if ((b=1)) {
            a=a;
        }
        if ((b=0)) {
            a=1;
        }
    }
    return(a);
}
```

Comment: Why so many conditions? And why inside the loop?

Comment: `if (b=1)` is not same as `if (b==1)`. You probably want to use the latter. Same with `if (b=0)`.

Comment: I did the common "new coder mistake" of the == sign. However it is now outputting one zero more than it should.  I don't need the function to work with negatives values :)

Comment: fixed it, thank you so much :)

Comment: Rethink your logic. This can be written in much more concise and elegant way. And correct. For example, this code is not going to work with `b=0`.

Comment: Are you allowed to use recursion?

Comment: @joop Are you thinking of O(log b) solution ? :)

Comment: @EugeneSh.: No, not *yet*

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simpler version (for better understanding):

```
int power(int a, int b)
{
    int p=1;                   //CHANGE
    for (int i=0; i<b; i++)    //CHANGE
    {
       p= p*a;                 //CHANGE
    }

    return (p);                //CHANGE
}
```

In your code the major error is initializing `p=a` and then `a=p*a` - even if **1** is passed as `b` the value comes out to be `100` in case of base `10`.

Answer (score 0):

1. You were setting `b` with the statements `b=1` and `b=0` as opposed to comparing `b` to 1 or 0
2. Your for loop condition included an extra iteration that results in the wrong output. You want `i < b` and not `i <= b`.
3. You try to handle special cases in your for loop but these can be handled outside of it easily (e.g. 0th power, 1st power, 1 to any power)

Here is your code with the above corrections

```
int power(int a, int b){

    /* 1 times 1 is always 1 */
    if(a == 1) return a;

    /* any number to the 0 power is always 1 */
    if(!b) return 1;

    /* any number to the 1 power is always itself */
    if(b == 1) return a;

    int p = a;

    for (int i = 1; i < b; i++){

        a = p*a;

    }

    return a;

}
```

I tested this [here](http://tpcg.io/Jdr5VQ) for powers of 2 from 0 to 10.

Comment: downvoting because even though it does *technically* answer the question, it doesn't fix the code smell in the OP's post.  plus the method won't work properly if `b` is 0.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I guess a better phrasing would of been: "Here's your code with those corrections". Didn't mean to condone bad coding practices. Forgive me. *insert prayer hands emoji here*

Answer (score 0):

- if you don't need it to work with negative values: use `unsigned`
- the recursive function uses only **one test**, it is tail-recursive so it can be unrolled
- the non-recursive version also uses **one test**: the loop condition
- Note: `gcc -O2` generates *exactly the same code* for these two functions

---

```
unsigned power1(unsigned val, unsigned exp)
{
if (!exp) return 1;
return val * power1(val, exp-1);
}

unsigned power2(unsigned val, unsigned exp)
{
unsigned result = 1;

while (exp--) result *= val;

return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The output is 100 because in second and third if statement you assign to b variable new number.

```
int power(int a, int b){
    int p=a;
    for (int i=1; i<b; ++i){
        if((b!=1) && (b!=0)){
            a= p*a;
        }
        if ((b==1)){
            a=a;
        }
        if ((b==0)){
            a=1;
        }    
    }
    return(a);
}
```